# Encoding JSON in Hidden Element

Tags: javascript, json, encoding

I've inherited some code. The previous developer was cramming JSON into a hidden HTML element. It works most of the time, except for when a single quote is included in one of the text strings. I'm not sure how to fix it. For example:

```
<input id="options" type="hidden" value='{"1":[{ "value":"101", "text":"Bill\'s"}, { "value":"102", "text":"Paul"}], "3":[{ "value":"201", "text":"Jack"}, { "value":"202", "text":"Jill"}]}' />
```

Fails during parsing. The parsing happens using the following line:

```
var options = JSON.parse($('#options).val());
```

How can I store single quotes in the value of a hidden HTML element so that I can parse it back into JSON in the JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, is that single-quote in the JSON the same one that went missing from your jQuery selector? ;)

Comment: you are missing a quote in 2nd line after options... it should be like this `var options = JSON.parse($('#options').val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&apos;` would be the HTML encoding for `'`. You have to do the replacement before generating the HTML (or manually if its not generated).

Comment: This is probably your best bet, aside from rewriting the code so this nonsense isn't necessary.

Comment: Well, replacing a `'` with `&pos;` will cause the output to appear correct if rendered to the user. But if that value is being interpreted by the browser, or sent back to the server, it's not going to have the same value because the characters are different. I'd probably try replacing the `\'` with `\\'` first, to ensure that the single-quote is properly 'escaped' when the HTML is generated.